# Fetching data from External Api to show in jsp using spring boot suite

Tags: java, api, jsp, spring-boot

i am very much new to spring and jsp kind of things.

I want to fetch data from a cricket api 
https://cricstatshub.com/2018/01/06/cricket-api-for-java/
OR
http://www.cricapi.com/

i am not able connect the api with my spring boot app.

Any help would be appreciated.

The thing i want to do is fetch data from api and show on front end.

Comment: Where and what exactly is the error?

Comment: as such there is no error but i don't know how to add the jar file in the spring boot and use it.

Comment: adding jar file is done. but not able to use it

Comment: also i want to show live match status, upcoming matches, ongoing, and previous matches

Comment: i want to know what should be the folder structure how to call the api by requestmapping for a particular link

Comment: It is clearly specified in the docs itself.

Comment: If you using pom. You should manually add the jar file to .m2 folder based on the package of cricbuzz.jar.